# Error while display map via gmap3

Tags: jquery, google-maps, coffeescript, jquery-gmap3

I am working on to display the map on my web screen. but facing some Error while displaying it.

Error :-

```
TypeError: $("#driver_map").gmap3 is not a function
```

Code :-

```
%script{:src=>'../assets/public/js/gmap3.js'}
%script{:src=>'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false' :type=>'text/javascript'}
%script{:src=>'../assets/public/js/jquery-1.6.4.js'}

%html
  %head
    %body
      %div{:id=>"driver_map"}

:javascript
  $(function(){
    $('#driver_map').gmap3(
      { action:'init',
        options:{
          center:[46.578498,2.457275],
          zoom: 5
        }
      },
      { action: 'addMarkers',
        markers:[
          {lat:48.8620722, lng:2.352047, data:'Paris !'},
          {lat:46.59433,lng:0.342236, data:'Poitiers : great city !'},
          {lat:42.704931, lng:2.894697, data:'Perpignan ! <br> GO USAP !'}
        ],            
      }
    );
  });
```

Please help me to solve this error.

Answer (score 1):

`gmap3.js` uses jQuery so it needs to be loaded after `jquery-1.6.4.js`. All the examples load things in this order:

1. jQuery
2. Google Maps
3. gmap3

so it might need to be loaded after the Google Maps JavaScript as well.

Try adjusting your load order:

```
%script{:src=>'../assets/public/js/jquery-1.6.4.js'}
%script{:src=>'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false' :type=>'text/javascript'}
%script{:src=>'../assets/public/js/gmap3.js'}
```

I'd also recommend against using relatives paths, they just cause trouble. You'd be better off with absolute paths like `'/assets/public/js/jquery-1.6.4.js'` so that you don't have to care about where you are.